# Dynamic Type in Unity?

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, types, enums

So let's say I have the following data types in my Equipable class:

```
public enum Slot { Primary, Secondary };

public enum Primary {RocketLauncher, SniperRifle };

public enum Secondary { MachineGun };
```

and I declare them to be available in the editor like so:

```
public Slot slot;

public Primary equipable;
```

This will result in the following available in the editor:

[image]

How could I go about dynamically changing the `equipable` type in order to see something like this?

[image]

Note:

I am rewriting a game and trying to keep it very neat.  I am capable of pulling this off with a little extra effort, but I was mostly wondering if I can pull this off using data types and playing games with declarations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom types instead of enums and then make use of polymorphism like this:

```
public class WeaponInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Equipable primarySlot;
    public Equipable secondarySlot;
}

public abstract class Equipable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slot slot;

    public enum Slot
    {
        Primary,
        Secondary
    }
}
```

*Equipable* is now an abstract *MonoBehaviour* component that needs to have a concrete implementation:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PrimaryEquipable : Equipable
{
    public Type type;

    public enum Type
    {
        RocketLauncher,
        SniperRifle,
    }
}
```

and

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SecondaryEquipable : Equipable
{
    public Type type;

    public enum Type
    {
        MachineGun,
        UnderwaterPulseRifle
    }
}
```

Note, that concrete *MonoBehaviour* components need to go in their own .cs file, which has the same name as the class or else Unity will complain.

[image]

Now both slots slots can be switched if you drag the title of one of the components onto the inspector field. So primary weapon goes into the secondary slot. (I would rethink the double use of *primary* and *secondary* in this case, maybe settle on an array of weapon slots and a weapon type of *primary* etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To change the slot from `Primary` to `Primary`:

```
slot = Slot.Secondary;
```

For `equipable`, you cannot change it to `MachineGun` because `MachineGun` is not defined in the `Primary` enum.

It would have been possible to change `equipable` to `MachineGun` with

```
equipable = Primary.MachineGun;
```

if your `Primary` enum is `public enum Primary { RocketLauncher, SniperRifle, MachineGun };`